# Como crear un formulario para una base de datos mysql existente

Tags: php, html, mysql

como puedo crear un formulario que guarde información en una tabla de una base de datos mysql existente??

Comment: Jhonatan Meza Bienvenido, esa pregunta es demasiado amplia necesitas mostrar código de avance o algo por el estilo , eso hacer dar cuenta que de verdad tienes dudas y problemas para resolver eso y que la comunidad acepte esta pregunta y no te la cierren.Te recomiendo editar la pregunta . Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que no ofreces una base de código para mostrarte la respuesta aquí te dejo un ejemplo sencillo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<form action="/controlador.php">
  Nombre:<br>
  <input type="text" name="nombre" value="Mickey">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Página `controlador.php`

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO nombres (primer_nombre) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param($nombre);

$nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
$stmt->execute();

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar. Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que son inciertas o deficientes en detalles específicos que puedan identificar el problema real. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: Si el usuario usa PDO esta respuesta no le vale. Las preguntas que no contienen suficiente información o que no se ajustan al formato y estilo del sitio deberían evitar responderse.